# bash operator within composer to copy most recent files from one GCS bucket to another

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I wrote the following DAG script (python code) which runs a BashOperator. It is weird because the bash command works smoothly when I launch the bash command into my terminal. But this same command when I wrap it into a BashOperatgor within an Airflow DAG.

The aim of this code is to copy the last files ( of today) from one GCS bucket to another bucket. Below is the code :

from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime

```
DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.now(),
    'retries': 0,
    'schedule_interval': None
}

with DAG('copy_input_files', default_args=DEFAULT_DAG_ARGS) as dag:
    pre_dag_cp = BashOperator(
        task_id='copy_current_files',
        bash_command="gsutil -m ls -l gs://input/files/UES | grep $(date -I) | sed 's/.*\(gs:\/\/\)/\1/'| gsutil cp -I  gs://output/recent_files "  + "\nexit 0"
    )
```

I get the following error :  `CommandException: No URLs matched: input/files/UES/TV11_INFODEB.2019_01_02_02.orc` and no files are copied as expected , when I test the bash command outside the dag in a basic terminal this works , Any idea how to fix this please

Comment: not particularly about this one, but have you tried the airflow operator for this specific task i.e gcs to gcs ? 
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py

Comment: I am trying to import it in my python files as follows : from airflow.contrib.operators import GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator
 but this doesn't work @vishnu narayanan

Comment: @ vishnu narayanan  do you know how to import it properly

Comment: which version of airflow are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Please look into the dedicated operator for this task.

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_gcs import GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

            copy_single_file = GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
                task_id='copy_single_file',
                source_bucket='data',
                source_object='sales/sales-2017/january.avro',
                destination_bucket='data_backup',
                destination_object='copied_sales/2017/january-backup.avro',
                google_cloud_storage_conn_id=google_cloud_conn_id
            )
```

Ref: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gcs.py